# Create a dataframe for each folder in folder (wav files)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to tell python to iterate a loop over every folder in a folder. This is the code that works with a manuel input of the path. Now I want the loop to do what it does, but automatically for every folder and save it into seperate dataframes with different names.

```
file_list = []
duration_list = []

for wave_file in glob.glob('path_name\*.wav'):
    sound = parselmouth.Sound(wave_file)
    duration = measurePitch(
        sound, 75, 300, "Hertz")
    file_list.append(wave_file)
    duration_list.append(duration)

# Add the data to Pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([file_list, duration_list]), columns=['voiceID', 'duration'])
```

Has someone a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do, just save the dataframe inside the loop.

```
save_path = "save_path/"
path_name = "C:\\Users\\guest\\Desktop\\test\\"

for index, wave_file in enumerate(glob.glob(f'{path_name}*.wav')):

    sound = parselmouth.Sound(wave_file)

    duration = measurePitch(sound, 75, 300, "Hertz")

    df = pd.DataFrame([[wave_file, duration]], columns=['voiceID', 'duration'])

    df.to_csv(f'{save_path}file_{index+1}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: How should I write the path name in the second line? I have a folder with folder with wav files. When I write 'C:\Users\guest\Desktop\test\**\*.wav' it does nothing.

Comment: It still saves nothing to the dirrectory. The error has to be in the third line. Before it, I can tell python to print something but after this line it does nothing.

Comment: what is the type of `duration` ? is it a float value ? also, since you seem to be using windows, make sure the save path is correctly put

Comment: duration is a number but it is treated as an object. There is no error message about the path I'm giving, so this should be correct.

Comment: can you print after `df` to see if it is being created correctly, just do a step by step debug.

Comment: It prints nothing after the third line

Comment: Sorry - it does nothing when I write save_glob.glob(r'{path_name}*.wav' . When I leave it that way with f I get PraatError: Not an audio file.
Sound not read from sound file “C:\Users\guest\Desktop\la2\labeled_VP_03VP03_F01_i.wav”. There is a slash missing between labeled_VP_03 and VP03_F01_i.wav